# How to implement a writable stream

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I want to pipe data from an amazon kinesis stream to a an s3 log or a bunyan log.

The sample works with a file write stream or stdout.  How would I implmeny my own writable stream?

```
//this works
var file = fs.createWriteStream('my.log')
kinesisSource.pipe(file)
```

this doesn't work saying it has no method 'on'

```
var stream = {}; //process.stdout works however
stream.writable = true;
stream.write =function(data){
    console.log(data);
};
kinesisSource.pipe(stream);
```

what methods do I have to implement for my own custom writable stream, the docs seem to indicate I need to implement 'write' and not 'on'

Answer (score 165, accepted):

To create your own writable stream, you have three possibilities.

## Create your own class

For this you'll need:

1. To extend the `Writable` class.
2. To call the Writable constructor in your own constructor.
3. To define a `_write()` method in the prototype of your stream object.

Here's an example:

```js
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

function EchoStream () { // step 2
  stream.Writable.call(this);
};
util.inherits(EchoStream, stream.Writable); // step 1
EchoStream.prototype._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) { // step 3
  console.log(chunk.toString());
  done();
}

var myStream = new EchoStream(); // instanciate your brand new stream
process.stdin.pipe(myStream);
```

## Extend an empty Writable object

Instead of defining a new object type, you can instanciate an empty `Writable` object and implement the `_write()` method:

```js
var stream = require('stream');
var echoStream = new stream.Writable();
echoStream._write = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
  done();
};

process.stdin.pipe(echoStream);
```

## Use the Simplified Constructor API

If you're using io.js, you can use the [simplified constructor API](https://iojs.org/api/stream.html#stream_simplified_constructor_api):

```js
var writable = new stream.Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    next();
  }
});
```

## Use an ES6 class in Node 4+

```
class EchoStream extends stream.Writable {
  _write(chunk, enc, next) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: to support object mode replace `chunk.toString()` per `chunk.toString ? chunk.toString() : chunk`

Comment: What does this line do: "util.inherits(EchoStream, stream.Writable); // step 1
"?

Comment: It makes `EchoStream` a "sub-class" of `stream.Writable`: its prototype methods are inherited from it and `stream.Writable` is accessible using the  `super_` property. See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor) for more information.

Comment: What's the benefit of "Create your own class" over "Extend an empty Writable object"?

Answer (score 11):

Actually to create a writeable stream is quite simple.
Here's is the example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Stream = require('stream');

var ws = new Stream;
ws.writable = true;
ws.bytes = 0;

ws.write = function(buf) {
   ws.bytes += buf.length;
}

ws.end = function(buf) {
   if(arguments.length) ws.write(buf);
   ws.writable = false;

   console.log('bytes length: ' + ws.bytes);
}

fs.createReadStream('file path').pipe(ws);
```

Also if you want to create your own class, @Paul give a good answer.

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined... at the buf.length in  ws.write function definition

Comment: should be buf.length

Comment: This may have been correct at one time, but not anymore. The Node documentation now says: "The stream.Writable class is extended to implement a Writable stream. Custom Writable streams must call the new stream.Writable([options]) constructor and implement the writable._write() and/or writable._writev() method." https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_writable_stream

Comment: This is completely wrong both logically and syntactically

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example directly from nodejs docs
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#an-example-writable-stream

```js
const { Writable } = require('stream');
class MyWritable extends Writable {
  _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    if (chunk.toString().indexOf('a') >= 0) {
      callback(new Error('chunk is invalid'));
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```