# Node.js create object.stdin

Tags: node.js, stream, stdin, readable

I have an object in node that has `.stdin`, `.stderr` and `.stdout` objects attached to it. I have `stdout` and `stderr` working as Writable streams and I'm having some trouble getting `stdin` to work as a Readable stream.

In the use case I'm building for I could do the following:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');
var Readable = stream.Readable;
var My_Stdin = function(){
    Readable.call(this, {objectMode: true});
};
util.inherits(My_Stdin, Readable);
My_Stdin.prototype._read = function(data) {
    this.emit(data);
};

function myObject(){
    this.stdin = new My_Stdin;

    this.stdin.on('data', function(data){
        process.stdout.write(data);
    });
}

var object = new myObject;
process.stdin.pipe(object.stdin);
```

Right now I'm getting an error that says:

> _stream_readable.js:525
>
> var ret = dest.write(chunk);
>                    ^
>
> TypeError: dest.write is not a function

How do I properly implement a `stdin` on my object similar to `child_process.spawn`?

Comment: I think you need use `Writeable` instead `Readable`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21583831/4989460

Comment: Why is process.stdin spec'd as a readable stream? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: I also need to be able to pipe object.stdin to other objects