# Using node Writable stream write data

Tags: node.js, stream

this is the code:

```
var stream = require('stream')
var ws = new stream.writable()
ws.write('hello')
```

but when run above code, it prompt

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: not implemented
    at Writable._write (_stream_writable.js:435:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:307:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:293:5)
    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/suoyong/Desktop/test.js:15:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

what's wrong with this code, thanks advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement your own writable stream. Take a look at this post for how to create your own: [How to implement a writable stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583831/5395709)

From the article - you can try something like this:

```
var stream = require('stream');

var ws = new stream.Writable({
  write: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    next();
  }
});
ws.write('hello');
```