# How to pipe with MongoDB Node.js Driver Cursor and AggregateCursor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pipe

Not sure of the proper way to pipe query results using [MongoDB Node.js Drive 3.0](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#pipe). According to the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Cursor.html#pipe), `Cursor::pipe` and `AggregateCursor::pipe` receive a Writeable streams so it seems like you should be able to do something like this:

```
collection.find(query).pipe(process.stdout);
collection.aggregate(query).pipe(process.stdout);
```

But it turns out to throw an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
```

This works but it feels a little cumbersome to me doesn't lend itself to pipe chaining.

```
collection.find(query)
    .on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(chunk))
        process.stdout.write( buffer );
    });


collection.aggregate(query)
    .on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(chunk))
        process.stdout.write( buffer );
    });
```

Is there a way to do a standard pipe chain with with the MongoDB Driver for Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the error was the result of my trying to pipe a stream in `objectMode` to a stream not in `objectMode`. Here is a solution:

```
collection.find(query)
    .stream({
        transform: function(chunk) {
            return JSON.stringify(chunk);
        }
    }).pipe(process.stdout);

collection.aggregate(query)
    .stream({
        transform: function(chunk) {
            return JSON.stringify(chunk);
        }
    }).pipe(process.stdout);
```

You could also [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491567/how-to-implement-a-writable-stream) `stream.Writable` and set it to `objectMode`, but the above seems like the simplest solution.