# How to check if a value/argument/resource is a writable stream in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know how to check if a value/argument/resource in node.js is a writable stream.

Is there a function or method to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I would really like to see this solved :D

Comment: why you need to do it?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: also what's your **definition of writable stream**, why you cannot **simply check it's definition** match or not.

Comment: hm.. definition of a writeable stream to them.. yea I'd like to know too.. whether it's just something u can pipe to or something more :D

Comment: What about just check `yourStream instanceof stream.Writable`? Obviously `stream = require('stream')` in node.js v0.9.4+

Comment: @DDomen actually.. ur correct :D unless they have a different definition of what a stream is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check

```js
// include node stream module
const stream = require('stream');

// check if stream is an instance of a Writable Stream
let isWritableStream = yourStream instanceof stream.Writable
```

**Note:** in your program, your customized *"Writable Stream Classes"* should extends the `stream.Writable` class. In order to extends it you may check [How to implement a writable stream (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491567/how-to-implement-a-writable-stream)

References:

1. [`stream.Writable` (Node.js v.0.9.4+)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable)
2. [`instanceof` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: btw.. I didn't even know before today that streams were LITERAL classes of things

Comment: You have a misconception about what a "class" in JS essentially is. JS is not an **Obect Oriented** but a **Prototype Oriented** programming language. Any class is infact a "special" `Function` object with a certain prototype. Checking an `instanceof` is just checking if the prototypes coincide. Node.js just exposes the V8 (engine) underlying `Function` object which is the prototype of all the internal stream implementations. It is not *LITERAL* a class, but a function, indeed you can call it without the `new` keyword: `stream.Writable()`, no errors.

Comment: I never said I didn't know(about prototypes).. it's just that it didn't really connect uk.. it's just.. a moment to take in