# React SSR with custom html

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-18

I'm began to use Suspense to my react app and then I turned it to SSR, but while reading the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertopipeablestream

I do not see anywhere **how to use a custom HTML**, before we used to replace the div#root to the renderToString() and you could add the **title of the document and meta tags**, now, with that function I only see how to return the html string from `<App />` with the `renderToPipeableStream` function:

```js
const stream = renderToPipeableStream(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
        <App
            data={json}
            pathLang={checkLanguage(lang) ? lang : ''}
            statusCode={status}
            cookiesAccepted={accepted}
        />
    </StaticRouter>,
    {
        onShellReady() {
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
            stream.pipe(res);
        },
    }
);
```

Is there any way to intercept the constructed html in order to place it into my `index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved it by creating my own **WritableStream** following https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900625/6732429 this way:

```js
// HtmlWritable.js
import {Writable} from 'stream';

class HtmlWritable extends Writable {
    chunks = [];
    html = '';

    getHtml() {
        return this.html;
    }

    _write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        this.chunks.push(chunk);
        callback();
    }

    _final(callback) {
        this.html = Buffer.concat(this.chunks).toString();
        callback();
    }
}

export default HtmlWritable;
```

and implementing it like this:

```js
// server.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {renderToPipeableStream} from 'react-dom/server';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom/server';
import {readFileSync} from 'fs';
import HtmlWritable from './HtmlWritable';

[...]
const writable = new HtmlWritable();
const stream = renderToPipeableStream(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}> // In an express js context
        <App />
    </StaticRouter>,
    {
        onShellReady() {
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
            stream.pipe(writable);
        },
    }
);

writable.on('finish', () => {
    const html = writable.getHtml();
    const indexHTML = readFileSync('./src/packages/api/html/index.html')
        .replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${html}</div>`);
    res.send(indexHTML); // In an express js context
});
[...]
```

Where `data` is the return `fs.readFile` of `index.html`.

That was my solution, if you solved it different, please share!

Thank a lot and feel free to comment, **I would like to know your opinion**!

Comment: That's working, thanks! I don't get why React doesn't still provide a `getHtml` function.

Comment: did you hydrate the root element with hydrateRoot and it worked as expected? in the React example they use hydrateRoot(document) after they stream the entire document as the React component.

Comment: @Gil you can hydrate or upload the JS you need in that specific page, I add hydation when I "compile" the project for SSR but in the compiler I do not use de "index.js" as you can see I use directly the React Components

Comment: Have you improved this solution over the years? Or is it still relevant today? Thx

Comment: @NicoSan Since It keeps working for me I still use the same solution, have you bumped into any issues? Or any better solution? Feel free to comment!

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but I was on vacation. Would you have a source to share or a more detailed example? At the moment I have the error: ReferenceError: resolve is not defined. I'm also wondering about the "status" variable. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: @NicoSan I removed all not related variables and tried to explain it a little bit more. Hope it helps!